# Cant persist data to the database? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel. My data doesn't seem to get to the database. Here's my Controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        'gender' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        'qualifications' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255'
    ];

    $validator = FacadesValidator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/home')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator);
    } else{
        $data = $request->input();
    
        try {
            $crud = new CRUD;
            $crud->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
            $crud->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
            $crud->gender = $request->get('gender');
            $crud->qualifications = $request->get('qualifications');
            $crud->save();
            
            return redirect('/home')->with('status',"Insert successfully");
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return redirect('/home')->with('failed',"Insert Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

And my Model:

```
protected $table = '$user';
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'qualifications'
];
public $timestamps = true;
```

And my route(Web.php):

```
Route::post('/store', [App\Http\Controllers\CRUDController::class, 'store'])->name('insert');
```

Here is my migration for the `users table`:

```php
Schema::create('user', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('gender');
    $table->string('qualifications');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: do you  get any error?

Comment: I didn't get any error, it just rerouted to home

Comment: If your model is `CRUD` then you should have a table like `Cruds`, but still, you named it `$user`... That should be avoided if you can create a table with that name, it is not standard... do you really have a `$user` table ? And it should also be `users`. Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) about tables and relations...

Comment: You can also take advantage of [`FormRequests`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) to prevent having a `Validator` in your controller, but have it in a better layer so your controller is cleaner.

Comment: The new error states that the function name must be a string...

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Yes, I have a `user` table and I'm sorry for not complying with the conventions as I'm just following an online tutorial. The `users` model and controller are being used to validate user registration thus the new user table was used.
The new error states that the **function name must be a string**...

Comment: In which file and what line is it giving that error ? As the code you shared, there is no `function name`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was troubleshooting using `$validator` at the catch clause. However, the result is that **Insert Failed** but I cannot seem to get why it is so

Comment: What error does it wring up ? remove the `try catch` and let the error show up.

Comment: This is the error: **SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_crud.$user' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `$user` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `qualifications`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Yellow, Stone, Female, Computer Scientist, 2021-04-23 20:54:40, 2021-04-23 20:54:40))**

And running `php artisan migrate` doesn't work

Comment: so, that is the problem, is your `Schema` table `users` or `user` or `$user` ? It should be `users` as I said before (and remove the `$table= '$user';` line).

Comment: That does not seem to work as well... My `Schema` table is `user`

Comment: Can you update your question with your migration ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti It's already done

Comment: you are requesting the $_GET variables with `$request->get()`, use `$request->post()`

Comment: @Sysix what ? it has nothing to do with that... @BenjaminNetan use `->input` always, not `->get`. Now, you can do `php artisan migrate` and show us what is wrong, and please, do not post images, they are going be to taken down, so post code not images please.

Comment: @matiaslauriti are u sure? Because He is filling his Model with `$request->get`. So it always get `null`. And his migration doesn't use `->nullable()`. Be more friendlier next time :)

Comment: I was not unfriendly, sorry if you took it like that. Still, the error was `function name must be a string`, that error means a function is like `$something` or `-something`, etc... so he fixed that, now he has a new error `table laravel_crud.$user` does not exist, so it has nothing to do with `$request` at all. Either way, if you see the `->get()` method phpdoc, it recommends you to always use `input`.

Comment: @Sysix the `$request->get()` does not return null, since it uses `SynfonyRequest` behind the scenes, and if it the key is not found via get, it checks all attributes and returns the one with the given name.

Comment: Thanks, guys it has worked. In the Model `$table= '$user';` it ought to have been `$table= 'user';`

Comment: @Benjaminnetan as I previously said, do not use `user` as a table name, stick to the Laravel convention, it is `users`, and model name should be `User`, then you don't have even to define `$table = 'something'`. Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) about this so you don't get confused and learn how it works when you don't see this variables defined.

Comment: Thank you @matiaslauriti I will make that amendment to `$table = 'something'` as in the documentation so as not to get confused. And thanks for the link to the documentation, it has helped me get a better grasp of the same

Comment: @MateusJunges thanks, learned something new. I always thought that is a PSR standard that will force that `->get()` will only look at `$_GET`. @matiaslauriti  the beginning was little harsh :) np was my unknowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your table name in your model, since your table is called `user`:

```php
protected $table = "user";
```

Also, you can use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) to fill your models:

```php
$crud = CRUD::create($request->validated());
```

It should fix your problem.